# get xmlSchema of xml?

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I have the file.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:test.001.001.01">
  <book>
  <author>Jack Herrington</author>
  <title>PHP Hacks</title>
  <publisher>O'Reilly</publisher>
  </book>
</Document>
```

anybody know How Can I get this information in the `<document....>`  example the `xmlns`?

```
<Document xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:test.001.001.01">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to get namespaces like so:

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:test.001.001.01">
  <book>
  <author>Jack Herrington</author>
  <title>PHP Hacks</title>
  <publisher>O'Reilly</publisher>
  </book>
</Document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$namespaces =  $xml->getDocNamespaces(); 
var_export($namespaces);
```

this code will produce:

```
array ( 'xsd' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', 'xsi' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', '' => 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:test.001.001.01', )
```

The array of all namespaces declared in the document.

Comment: if so how we can  '' => 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:test.001.001.01' because its key empty?

Comment: I think you confused `getDocNamespaces` and `getNamespaces` functions of `SimpleXML`

Comment: but if you curious, in your example, key is not empty. It's just an empty sting ;) `var_export( $array[''] )` will work. You can create such an array: `$arr = array('' => 'Hello, World!')`